# GraphQL naming convention when objects and models have "Type" in their names

Tags: graphql, naming-conventions

It feels weird asking about this, but I'm at a point where I really just need to ask someone.

I'm developing a GraphQL schema using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Graphene](https://graphene-python.org/). Everything works fine. The problem I have is what to name some of the GraphQL types, namely those that actually represent... types!

Say I have models named `Engine` and `EngineType`, `Processor` and `ProcessorType`, where an engine might be "gas engine" or "steam engine", and a processor type might be "x86" or "ARM" or whatever. (These are made up examples. My project has a ton of these types-of-something models.)

The convention in Graphene (and GraphQL more generally, as far as I can tell), is that types are called `*Something*Type`. This means that the GraphQL types for the above-mentioned models would be GraphQL type `EngineType` for `Engine`, `EngineTypeType` for `EngineType` and `ProcessorType` for `Processor` and `ProcessorTypeType` for `ProcessorType`.

Not only does this reek of a the print-function-factory-making-factory pattern prevalent in some more bloated Java frameworks, but also this makes an already rather convoluted GraphQL nomenclature even more convoluted. When I refer to `ProcessorType`, do I mean the model for a type of processor, or a GraphQL type for the processor model?

I had thought of solving this by banning the use of the suffix "type" in model names, using something like "kind" instead, so: `Engine`, `EngineKind`, `Processor` and `ProcessorKind`, which then results in `Engine`, `EngineType`, `EngineKind and` EngineKindType` and so forth.

This, in short, feels icky, and demans that I enforce rules that developers are likely to miss, forget, ignore or just find plain annoying.

Another terrible way of solving it is importing models as `ProcessorModel` (`from processor import Processor as ProcessorModel`) and then using `Processor` both in the model file and the GraphQL schema file. Same problem: very convoluted, always forces the programmer to keep more things in mind than is otherwise necessary and requires discipline on behalf of developers that I'd prefer not having to enforce.

How do people using GraphQL generally solve this? Is there a widely accepted practice for dealing with it?

That's the problem. Any input appreciated. Hope this isn't too far out of StackOverflow's scope. Seeing the `naming-conventions` tag I figured I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Hi there, did you figure this out? I found surprisingly few topics/threads on this, as I assumed that most people need to consider this.

Comment: @A.Prams - Instead of appending "Type", we ended up prepending "T". So, in the example above, we would have the model Engine and its GraphQL type TEngine, EngineType and TEngineType and so forth.

It's not ideal to re-introduce Hungarian notation like that, in my opinion, but this was honestly the least awful way we found. We got used to it pretty quickly.

But we're also slowly ditching GraphQL in favor of REST, because it turns out that the cost/benefit of GraphQL doesn't compute in our favor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me!